# .gitlab-ci.yml for C# using Docker image mono

Tags: c#, build, mono, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup `gitlab-ci` runner for building c# apps. Already setup `gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker, runner` with `mono image`.

I'm trying to `xbuild` example.sln but need to get `nuget packages` required and I dont know how.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` currently looks like this. it will get into building but errors for missing packages.

```
before_script:

build:
 script:
    - xbuild  "example.sln"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the before script, you need to install and run the nuget command line client, same as you would do using bash, to get your dependencies before building your project.

EDIT: Ok nuget is already installed on official mono image, so you should just do this :

```
before_script:
    - nuget restore -NonInteractive

build:
 script:
    - xbuild  "example.sln"
```

Not sure about the nuget command as I'm not familiar with C# and Mono

Comment: Thanks for answer, I used `- nuget restore example.sln` and worked.

Answer (score 2):

It took me some time to figure out how to run NUnit tests, especially since the Mono template from Gitlab isn't up to date anymore and therefore I had to figure out the correct path to the nuget packages:

```
image: mono:latest

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - nuget restore
  - MONO_IOMAP=case xbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" MyPlugin.sln

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - nuget restore
  - MONO_IOMAP=case xbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" MyPlugin.sln
  - mono /root/.nuget/packages/nunit.consolerunner/3.9.0/tools/nunit3-console.exe Plugin.Tests/bin/Release/Plugin.Tests.dll
```